# having problems in enabling sound feature in my dictionary api code

Tags: javascript

I am trying to enable a sound feature on my dictionary API but am having problems with my code since its not working

```
const url = "https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en/";
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const sound = document.getElementById("sound");
const btn = document.getElementById("search-btn");

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let inpWord = document.getElementById("inp-word").value;
    fetch(`${url}${inpWord}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            result.innerHTML = `
            <div class="word">
                    <h3>${inpWord}</h3>
                    <button onclick="playSound()">
                        <i class="fas fa-volume-up"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please post your code, instead of an image.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)